# Autofilling a form using the Play Framework

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a form that contains some values. When POSTed to the server, the server validates the information, and if any of the fields are invalid, is supposed to return the filled form.

The way I currently have it set up is like this.

I have a form that validates 2 fields.

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "age" ->  number(min=0, max=100)
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

If the form fails to bind, I load up the same form with the values they just posted.

```
 def createItem() = IsAuthenticated {
   username =>
      implicit request => {
        createExperienceForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
          formWithErrors => BadRequest(
            views.html.createItem(formWithErrors)
          ),
          validForm => {
            val itemCode = Item.createItem(validForm)
            Redirect(routes.Item.item(itemCode).url)
          }
        )
      }
  }
```

The problem is that I have to manually set the value in my HTML page for each form. eg.
    @(itemForm: Form[ItemContent])

```
<input name="age" type="number" class="input-block-level" value="@itemForm.data.get("age")">
```

While this works, it will become a bit error prone on larger forms. For every single field, I need to set the value directly. Is it possible to autofill these fields?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by 'autofilling'. You can use standard play helpers like: @inputText(createExperienceForm("name"), '_label -> "Name") which will set the value of your fields automatically

Comment: And if the layout of the default helper isn't fitting your needs, you can always override it ! http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaFormHelpers

Comment: Try [metawidget](http://metawidget.org/) with javascript

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says something about it http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms - scroll down to "Fill values"

`val userForm = userForm.fill(User("Bob", 18))`